# Database schema advice for real time API calls

Tags: php, database, file, api, content-management-system

I have a project for some local high school sport leagues which want some real time updates with statistics.  There will be people at events (american football, basketball, volleyball, golf, wrestling, etc) who will be using my CMS system to update the stats.

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to store those stats so when the REST API calls happen, the latest events will be sent back (ex: gathering all basketball games happening at that time on the server and saving them).

The data coming to the server is in JSON format and I would like to be able to store it as so, each sport being the main key, then the stats on a game by game basis.  It seems to me using a RDBMS or another db type would be pointless because adding the stats in real time would mean a ton of rows where the data barely differs, then collecting the most recent games would be a pain if I were to break up each person's `POST` and save it as it's own row.

On the other hand, I could just store everything in a file, gather the stats as they come in and update the file.  But if there will be many writes happening, the responses to the API calls might get slow.

Any suggestions?  Which of my thoughts is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing data as JSON generally limits your ability to query the data. I would suggest against that. JSON is perfectly acceptable format to accept on the server, but you should immediately deserialize it into an object and store it in a way that will meet your use cases. In my opinion your use cases demand a relational database. E.g. a schema like this would give you good performance finding all games that are happening:

```
Sport:
    pk int sportId
       varchar description

Game:
    pk int gameId
    fk int sportId
       datetime start
       datetime end 

Player:
    pk int playerId
       varchar name

StatType:
    pk int statTypeId
       varchar description

Stat:
    pk bigint statId
    fk int gameId
    fk int playerId
    fk int statTypeId
       datetime time
       real value
```

To get the current game:

```
SELECT * FROM Game WHERE currentTime > start AND end IS NULL
```

To get all time stats for a player

```
SELECT max(st.description), sum(value) FROM Stat s LEFT JOIN StatDescription st ON s.statTypeId = st.statTypeId LEFT JOIN Player p ON s.playerId = p.playerId GROUP BY st.statTypeId WHERE p.name = 'John Smith'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Wouldn't the database grow really really fast if for one, say 2.5 hour game, there might be over 100 updates?  Would I just need to clean it on a regular basis because I think the stats rows would reach into millions more or less quickly?

Comment: Most relational database management systems are capable of handling huge numbers of rows (hundreds of millions and billions) no problem. For example at my company we were using MS SQL Server to store "stats" from tens of thousands of things every minute. Our database was several terabytes (mostly one table) before we decided to move away from a relational database. It's all about designing your schema correctly so that you can query your data efficiently. If you do that, it won't matter how much raw data there is. Plus it sounds like you're starting off small, and you definitely don't want to

Comment: write your own file-based database system